# page url sent via workflow

Tags: workflow, 2016

We have sharepoint 2016 site with a feedback list displayed at bottom of all pages throughout the site.  It simply reads:  How can this page be improved?

An email is sent via workflow to the sharepoint team anytime a user provides feedback.  However, we need the page url or page name the user was on when they provided feedback.  Not the item url and not the list url, because again, the same list is displayed on all pages via webparts.

Thanks,
SharePointGoToGuy

Comment: How are you displaying your list at bottom?  Through any custom ui or client side web part? If so then think of _spPageContextInfo object it has members of your interest.

Comment: Hi Asad.  Thanks for the reply.  I am using the out-of-the-box web part.  Add Web Part, then I select my custom Feedback list.